# How to pass data from the View textbox to Controller using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, razor

I want to pass **data** from Textbox value to the controller. The Textbox Value its string and on the controller, it must be converted to double. But I seem to fail on the presented code below. I don't know why the code does not work.

===**VIEW CODE**===

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("OnceOff"))
  {
    <div class="container">
     <div class="bg hidden-sm"></div>

      <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Once-Off Payment</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <input type="text" id="smsbundles" name="smsbundles" value="50" />

                </div>
                <div class="text-right">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Buy Now", "OnceOff", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-success" })

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

     </div> 
  </div>
           }
```

===**CONTROLLER**===

```
   public ActionResult OnceOff(string smsbundles)
    {
        double bundle = Convert.ToDouble(smsbundles);
        var onceOffRequest = new PayFastRequest(this.payFastSettings.PassPhrase);

        // Merchant Details
        onceOffRequest.merchant_id = this.payFastSettings.MerchantId;
        onceOffRequest.merchant_key = this.payFastSettings.MerchantKey;
        onceOffRequest.return_url = this.payFastSettings.ReturnUrl;
        onceOffRequest.cancel_url = this.payFastSettings.CancelUrl;
        onceOffRequest.notify_url = this.payFastSettings.NotifyUrl;

        // Buyer Details
        onceOffRequest.email_address = "";

        // Transaction Details
        onceOffRequest.m_payment_id = "***";
        onceOffRequest.amount = bundle;  //30 or 50
        onceOffRequest.item_name = "Once off option";
        onceOffRequest.item_description = "Some details about the once off payment";

        // Transaction Options
        onceOffRequest.email_confirmation = true;
        onceOffRequest.confirmation_address = "****";

        var redirectUrl = $"{this.payFastSettings.ProcessUrl}{onceOffRequest.ToString()}";

        return Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input `smsbundles` is an input element inside a form. 
You are using `ActionLink` helper, that generates `<a>` element that does not submit the form. That's the reason your controller action code is called with a null value of `smsbundles`.

Replace you `ActionLink` to a regular submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="btn btn-block btn-success" />
```